# Cauchy problem for an ordinary equation not in normal form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Let's consider a one-dimensional physical system ($x$ is the position and $t$ is time) described by a first order differential equation.

I'm aware of the fact that if the equation can be put in normal form:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=f(x,t)
\end{equation}
the Cauchy problem, provided some mathematical hypotheses are verified, tells us that the equation admits the existence of an unique solution. Therefore the system is deterministic, i.e., given the initial conditions there is only one admissible motion.

I was wondering what happens when the system is described by an equation that cannot be put in normal form:
\begin{equation}
g(\dot{x},x,t)=0
\end{equation}
Is there anything that proves that the Cauchy problem still provides the existence of an unique solution for an equation not in normal form or are there specific conditions?

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640831/2451

Comment: dear Simo, I think this is quite a good question (+1), and I'm sorry to see it's receiving close votes. I recommend, in order to avoid having the question closed, to remove question $2$, since it is unrelated to the rest of the question. (I suspect that's likely part of the reason that it's receiving close votes under the banner "needs more focus".) probably it's worth asking question $2$ as a separate question, and making this one focused on question $1$ :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thank you for your feedback. Will do this and post the second question in another moment. Actually I noticed that the matter of putting the equation in normal form can be tackled within the environment of the inverse function theorem. So perhaps there is no need.

Answer (score 1):

For the function $g(v,x,t)$ consider the set $D=\{(v,x,t):\partial_vg(v,x,t)\ne 0\}$. On this set the equation is locally solvable as $v=f(x,t)$ which gives an ODE $\dot x=f(x,t)$. In the complement of this set the equation does not depend on $v$, it is just a functional equation in $x,t$ so that the implicit function theorem again applies in telling you if $x$ is locally a function of $t$.

More generally, if $x$ is a vector, if the implicit equation can not be transformed into an explicit ODE, the next best thing you can hope for is that it is a differential-algebraic equation (DAE). This would be the case if one of the closely related index definitions gives a constant index over some open domain.

Comment: So you're saying that there is no "general theorem" if the equation is not in general form?